# All files from shared folder appear empty

Tags: macos, sharing, file-sharing

I have a mac mini that's serving files over the network (Through the "sharing" part of the preferences). All files have a size, and are accessable locally. but when I try to `cat` them on the terminal off the network or copy them to my local HD I get empty files only .

The permissions are set to allow everyone to both read and write. It's set to operate using the SMB protocol, and I've been trying to access it by clicking the machine name under the "shared" title on the left pane of "Finder" and logging in.

The mac has the "Mac server" program installed, not sure if it's relevant.

Comment: It would be helpful to know which file sharing protocol you're using on the server, and which method(s) specifically you're using to access the files with the client.

Comment: To be clear, you're _not using_ the file services available with macOS Server, just serving files through `System Preferences > Sharing`?

Comment: @IconDaemon yes. I mentioned the macOS server because I figured that a conflict isn't impossible

Comment: On what path does this shared folder reside on the disk directory? Is the shared folder on an internal drive (boot or otherwise) or on an external drive (USB, Firewire, etc)?

Comment: @IconDaemon it is on an external hard drive

Comment: Are you sharing from the root of the external drive, or from a folder on the root of the external drive?

Comment: @IconDaemon form a folder